# #define FOO(x) bar, x never referenced in definition, what happens?

Tags: c-preprocessor

I found some legacy code with something similar to the following.  Say I have the following definition:

```
#define FOO(x) bar
```

x is never referenced in the definition.  So, does that mean that whatever text is placed within FOO() is irrelevant?

The code I'm looking at is scattered with calls such as `FOO(someValue);` I'm assuming the preprocessor is replacing the entire statement with simply `bar`, no matter what `someValue` is?  A little thrown off by why `x` is present at all.

Comment: I guess someone felt that throwing away 'x' was a good idea... Suggestion: get rid of the ugly macro and fix the call sites once you've found out what the code is *supposed* to do.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, if x is not usted then x is not evaluated, in case of doubt see the output of the preprocessor using `cpp prog.c`

Comment: @JesperJuhl: There might still be a valid reason to have a macro that ignores its argument. For example, as [Daniel Jour's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39088130/827263) suggests, there might be an alternative definition of the macro that does use its argument.

Comment: Sure, but in that case I'd still get rid of the macro and just have alternative functions that either use or ignore the argument. No reason for a macro.

Comment: Definitely no conditional defines taking place.  Most likely a poorly refactored change, or maybe someone just decided they wanted to type more characters ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @schumacher574 sounds like it's time to dig through your VCS history/logs :)

Comment: @Olaf, the c preprocessor is also part of C, why remove the C tag?

Comment: @AlterMann: Because this is not about the C or C++ core-languages (the question was actually tagged with both) and would yield the same results when run on any other text using cpp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `FOO(whatever)` is completely replaced with `bar` in your example.

Macros like this are often seen in "configure-able" code, like:

```
#if defined(ENABLE_DEBUG_PRINT)
#define DEBUG_PRINT(msg) printf("Here's a message: %s\n", msg)
#else
#define DEBUG_PRINT(msg) /* empty */
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

Nothing special happens. Any occurrence of `x` in the macro definition is expanded to the value of the corresponding argument when the macro is expanded. If there is no such occurrence, it's not expanded (and the actual value of the argument is irrelevant).

As for why it's there, it may be that some past or potential future version of the macro might make some use of the argument. Perhaps it's one of several macros that take a single argument, and it's defined that way for consistency. It's impossible to tell without more context. But the macro definition is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2):

What happens is exactly what you thought would happen—the value is ignored.
I recommend running the preprocessor (`gcc -E` or `cpp` (possibly add `-x c++` for c++)) to actually see what actually happens on your implementation instead of just guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, macro `FOO()` expands to `bar` regardless of its argument.  This is not different in nature from how a function can ignore some or all of its parameters.

The macro may be a place holder for a possible future implementation that does use its argument, or a replacement for an older implementation that did.  It may also be that the definition of macro `FOO()` is different in different places, and that some of the definitions use their argument.  If it isn't any of those, nor similar, then it's just obfuscatory.

Comment: Well, there is a difference with functions, parameters are evaluated even if they are not used inside the function, e.g `func(++a);`

Comment: @AlterMann, you are quite correct.  By "not different in nature" I simply mean to point out that functions don't necessarily use their arguments either.  It is indeed an important distinction that a function argument will be evaluated even if it will then go unused in the function, whereas a macro argument that does not appear in the macro's replacement text is not evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

> So, does that mean that whatever text is placed within FOO() is irrelevant?

Unless there's a conditionally-compiled alternative version of `FOO()` where `x` is actually used. You might that to only evaluate the expression `x` in the debug build, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

This statement just consumes the `x` expression without using it.

For instance, if you want to stub some methods you can use that.